# Image cropping with absolute pixel values

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to crop a small part of an image. I used ImageMagick command for this as below:

```
convert image.jpg -crop 6x6+16+16 +repage image_crop.jpg
```

However, when I try to compare pixel values in both the images for the same block, it doesn't match. For example, pixel value at position (16,16) in `image.jpg` should match with pixel value at (0,0) in `image_crop.jpg`. Any ideas on how to crop an image so that pixel values are not modified?

Note: I'm comparing the pixel values by dumping the image data into a text file as below:

```
convert image.jpg image.txt
```

Comment: Do you get the same result when writing to a lossless format like PNG?

Comment: @nwellnhof Yes, it is same. It means it was changing the pixel values due to lossy nature of JPEG whereas it retains values in PNG.